# How to place in the middle v-aligment of cell? in a tabular/table with graphs?

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

How can I place a word in the middle by v-aligment?

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,x11names,landscape]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,mwe}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{incgraph,graphicx,subcaption}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
  \hline
   & $r_i=0.75$ & $r_i=0.50$ & $r_i=0.01$ \\ \hline
   $m=3$ & \includegraphics[width=.26\linewidth]{example-image-a.eps} & \includegraphics[width=.26\linewidth]{example-image-a.eps} &  \includegraphics[width=.26\linewidth]{example-image-a.eps} \\ \hline
       $m=6$ & \includegraphics[width=.26\linewidth]{example-image-b.eps} & \includegraphics[width=.26\linewidth]{example-image-b.eps} & \includegraphics[width=.26\linewidth]{example-image-b.eps} \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Matriz comparativa de factor de reducción vs iteraciones en estabilidad}\label{tab:factordereduccionvsitenestabilidad}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `adjustbox` package is your friend; not only it allows to shift the images down, but it allows pad them so they won't touch the rules.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,x11names,landscape]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{incgraph,graphicx,subcaption}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
  & $r_i=0.75$ & $r_i=0.50$ & $r_i=0.01$ \\ \hline
$m=3$ &
  \includegraphics[width=.26\linewidth,valign=c,padding=2pt]{example-image-a} &
  \includegraphics[width=.26\linewidth,valign=c,padding=2pt]{example-image-a} &
  \includegraphics[width=.26\linewidth,valign=c,padding=2pt]{example-image-a} \\
\hline
$m=6$ &
  \includegraphics[width=.26\linewidth,valign=c,padding=2pt]{example-image-b} &
  \includegraphics[width=.26\linewidth,valign=c,padding=2pt]{example-image-b} &
  \includegraphics[width=.26\linewidth,valign=c,padding=2pt]{example-image-b} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\caption{Matriz comparativa de factor de reducción vs iteraciones en 
estabilidad}\label{tab:factordereduccionvsitenestabilidad}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: the solution is perfect but I´m tryin and no succes!! what do you add to the original code?. The only change I view is \usepackage[export]{adjustbox}. Any more?. If I copy&paste your code I obtain the good result.

Comment: @MikaIke Yes, the key is `\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}`

Comment: I was trying and I must add ",valign=c" in the options of includegraphicx. That´s the key!. Thank you egreg.